# What is the best way to create Slide in Animation for 2 text widgets sequentially one after the other. FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, animation

[enter image description here][1]I want to have 2 different text widgets slide in one after the other (e.g. title and subtitle) automatically when the screen loads.

Seems simple enough!

I can achieve this animation effect easily by writing the code used to support a SlideTransition. And then duplicating this as per the code snippet below (e.g. 2 animition controllers, 2 animation objects, 2 slide transition widgets). With the 2 animation controllers wrapped in a future delay set at two slightly different times. However, this seems like a very inefficent way to achieve this simple task.

Note:
I have tried and failed achieving this effect with using TweenSequence (which appears suited for multiple animations on the SAME object).

I also made this work using an Animated List, but again the amount of extra code to support an animated list seemed over-the-top for 2 widgets.

Does anyone know what the preferred way / less verbose way to achieve this would be (preferably with just one animationcontroller)?

Thanks!!

```
/// setting up the slide transition and duplicating the animcontroller etc to support the slide animation.

class _MenuPageState extends State<MenuPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late _animControllerSlideIn,
      _animControllerSlideIn2;

  late Animation<Offset> _slideIn, _slideIn2;
 
  @override
  void initState() {

    _animControllerSlideIn = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);

    _slideIn = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1.1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0)).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animControllerSlideIn, curve: Curves.easeOut));

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 800), () {
      _animControllerSlideIn.forward();
    });

    _animControllerSlideIn2 = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);

    _slideIn2 = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1.1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0)).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
            parent: _animControllerSlideIn2, curve: Curves.easeOut));

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1200), () {
      _animControllerSlideIn2.forward();
    });


/////////



child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: [
                                Flexible(
                                  child: SlideTransition(
                                    child: Text('Text 1',),
                                    position: _slideIn,
                                  ),
                                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                ),
                                Flexible(
                                  child: SlideTransition(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Text 2!',),
                                    position: _slideIn2,
                                  ),
                                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qlAI.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another approach is to create a stateful widget class for the sliding text, and passing interval to this widget class:

```
    class SlidingText extends StatefulWidget {
      final String word;
      final int interval;
      final bool isDelay;
      
      SlidingText ({this.word, this.interval, this.isDelay});
      
      @override
      _SlidingTextState createState() => _SlidingTextState();
    }
    
    class _SlidingTextState extends State<SlidingText> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      late AnimationController _animControllerSlideIn;
      late Animation<Offset> _slideIn;
     
      @override
      void initState() {
        _animControllerSlideIn = AnimationController(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: widget.interval), vsync: this);
    
        _slideIn = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1.1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0)).animate(
            CurvedAnimation(parent: _animControllerSlideIn, curve: Curves.easeOut));
    
        if(widget.isDelay){
            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 800), () {
              _animControllerSlideIn.forward();
            });
        }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
                                    child: Text(widget.word),
                                    position: _slideIn,
                                  );
```

and use it with:

```
child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: [
                                Flexible(
                                  child: SlidingText('Text 1', 800, true),
                                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                ),
                                Flexible(
                                  child: SlidingText('Text 2', 800, true),
                                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),
```

Comment: Awesome. Yes this worked! Also I can implement this class where I want in the app.

Comment: Note on minor housekeeping to any future readers on the accepted answer: 1) I changed the Ticker back to a SingeTickerProviderStateMixin and placed it on the State class instead. 2) I added in The AnimationController type. 3) and there should be one more curly brace before the Widget build method at the bottom which will make it work. Thank you for your help!